# How to handle ellipsis and multiline flex with align items?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me with this? Right now the text is going into multiple lines and I have to restrict it up to 2 lines and then ellipsis.
Also the image needs to be in the second line then with vertically alignment of second line.

I've used align-items: center but it works fine for single line only. When it is in 2 lines it moves as shown in this image.

[image]

This image is now considered as another flex item, I was expecting it just to the right of last word in the text.

As expected in single line.

[image]

```css
.rp-scenario-content-ctaButtons{
    display: flex;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.rp-custom-links-preview{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="rp-scenario-content-ctaButtons">
  <span class="rp-custom-links-preview">
    Click here to see Click here to see  Click here to see Click here to see  
    <img src="/img/External.svg">
  </span>
  <i class="el-icon-arrow-right"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: I really don't know what your expectations are. If the text is longer then it will break in a new line. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 - Yeah so it should maximum go to 2 lines then ellipsis. Also the image should be next to the 3 dots of ellipsis. In this case it is going far away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below snippet it up to 2 lines and then ellipsis with help of `display:box;` property.

```css
.rp-scenario-content-ctaButtons{
    display: flex;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 350ms;
}
.rp-scenario-content-ctaButtons:hover,
.rp-scenario-content-ctaButtons:hover .el-icon-arrow-right{
    color: blue;
}
.rp-custom-links-preview{
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.rp-image{
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: 350ms;
}
.rp-scenario-content-ctaButtons:hover .rp-image{
    opacity: 0.5;   
}
.el-icon-arrow-right{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    min-width: 20px;
    color: #888;
    border-top: 2px solid currentColor;
    border-right: 2px solid currentColor;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: 350ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="rp-scenario-content-ctaButtons">
    <span class="rp-custom-links-preview">
       Click here
    </span>
    <img class="rp-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hmfs.png">
    <i class="el-icon-arrow-right"></i>
</div>
<br>
<div class="rp-scenario-content-ctaButtons">
    <span class="rp-custom-links-preview">
        Click here to see Click here to see Click here to see Click here to see
    </span>
    <img class="rp-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hmfs.png">
    <i class="el-icon-arrow-right"></i>
</div>
<br>
<div class="rp-scenario-content-ctaButtons">
    <span class="rp-custom-links-preview">
       Click here to see Click here to see Click here to see Click here to see Click here to see Click here to see Click here to see Click here to see
    </span>
    <img class="rp-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hmfs.png">
    <i class="el-icon-arrow-right"></i>
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent needs to be changed from flex to inline.
Change the child to

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Give margin top to the image for vertical alignment.